# Replacing items in a list one at a time

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, function

I am trying to write a "fill in the blanks" for a python class I'm taking. I'm only near the beginning and I'm running into something I don't quite understand.

Here is the main block of code:

```
easy = ['In ','___(1)___',' if you want to pass the W3 validator, make sure you close your ','___(2)___','!']

easy_list = ['HTML','tags']
blank_list = ['___(1)___','___(2)___','___(3)___','___(4)___','___(5)___','___(6)___']

def num_replace(level,word):
    new_level = []
    for i in level:
        if i == blank_list[word]:
            new_level[word] = easy_list[word]
        else:
            new_level.append(i)
    return new_level
```

I've tried outputting the function as simple prints like this:

```
print ''.join(num_replace(easy,0))
print ''.join(num_replace(easy,1))
```

But I'll I get is:

```
HTML if you want to pass the W3 validator, make sure you close your ___(2)___!
```

and then...

```
In tags if you want to pass the W3 validator, make sure you close your !
```

So instead I tried outputting it like this:

```
happy_list = ''.join(num_replace(easy,0))
print happy_list
happy_list = ''.join(num_replace(easy,1))
print happy_list
```

But I get the same thing.

To clarify what I'm trying to get is:

Before calling num_replace: `In ___(1)___ if you want to pass the W3 validator, make sure you close your ___(2)___!`

num_replace(easy,0) should output: `In HTML if you want to pass the W3 validator, make sure you close your ___(2)___!`

num_replace(easy,1): `In HTML if you want to pass the W3 validator, make sure you close your tags!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues here:

1 - You are appending the new word at `word`th position. `new_level[word] = append(easy_list[word])`
2 - You are not saving the changing to a new string since strings are not mutuable.
So here is the change:

```
>>> def num_replace(level, word):
        new_level = []
        for i in level:
            if i == blank_list[word]:
                new_level.append(easy_list[word])
            else:
                new_level.append(i)
        return new_level

>>> 
>>> 
>>> ''.join(num_replace(easy,0))
'In HTML if you want to pass the W3 validator, make sure you close your ___(2)___!'
>>> ''.join(num_replace(easy,1))
'In ___(1)___ if you want to pass the W3 validator, make sure you close your tags!'
>>>
```

Now, you have to save the change you made, this way:

```
>>> l = num_replace(easy,0)
>>> l
['In ', 'HTML', ' if you want to pass the W3 validator, make sure you close your ', '___(2)___', '!']
>>> 
>>> ''.join(num_replace(l,1))
'In HTML if you want to pass the W3 validator, make sure you close your tags!'
>>>
```

Or if you want it in one line:

```
>>> ''.join(num_replace(num_replace(easy,0),1))
'In HTML if you want to pass the W3 validator, make sure you close your tags!'
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is that you are trying to modify a global variable from inside a function whilst at the same time returning a new list of words.

If you look closely in your loop you'll see that unmatched blank entries are `.append(..)`ed. Thus so you should do with the replacement words as well.

I think your loop should look like this:

```
for i in level:
        if i == blank_list[word]:
            new_level.append( easy_list[word] )
        else:
            new_level.append(i)
```

**Maybe better**

```
replacements = { '__(1)__': 'HTML', '__(2)__': 'tags' }

def replace(wordlist, subs):
   res = []
   for word in wordlist:
      res.append( subs[word] if word in subs else word )
   return res
```

Comment: I tried that originally, but it only returns: In HTML if you want to pass the W3 validator, make sure you close your ___(2)___! and then 
In ___(1)___ if you want to pass the W3 validator, make sure you close your tags!

Comment: Well of course. Your function replaces *one word at a time*. If you ask for word #0 to be replaced, then that is exactly what it will do; if you ask for `__(1)__` to be replaced then `__(2)__` will be passed on unmodified.

Comment: So how would I go about replacing word 0 then 1 etc? Maybe a while loop that calls this function?

Comment: Make a `dict` of `string` to `replacement` and then do it in one go

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, When (num_replace(easy,0)). You are overwriting the new_level's `0th` position in this step `new_level[word] = easy_list[word]` So you are not getting `In`

Step 1:

[image]

Step 2:

[image]

new_level[0] is replaced by HTML

Change this to

```
if i == blank_list[word]:
            new_level.append( easy_list[word] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion:

```
easy = ['In ','___(1)___',' if you want to pass the W3 validator, make sure you close your ','___(2)___','!']

easy_list = ['HTML','tags']
blank_list = ['___(1)___','___(2)___','___(3)___','___(4)___','___(5)___','___(6)___']

def num_replace(level, replacement_list, *words):
    new_level = level[:]
    for word in words:
        level_pos = level.index('___(%d)___' % (word+1))
        new_level[level_pos] = replacement_list[word]

    return new_level

print ''.join(num_replace(easy,easy_list,0,1))
```

So we pass a *tuple* of positions (0,1) into *words.   I'm also passing in the replacement list (rather than using a global) for flexibility.

But it would be much simpler if you just used a string rather than a list.

```
easy = 'In ___(1)___ if you want to pass the W3 validator, make sure you close your ___(2)___!'

easy_list = ['HTML','tags']

def num_replace(level, replacement_list, *words):
    new_level = level
    for word in words:
        new_level = new_level.replace('___(%d)___' % (word+1), replacement_list[word])

    return new_level

print num_replace(easy,easy_list,0,1)
```

Of course here you are creating a new string object for each "word", but with the volumes involved (2) then that is hardly worth worrying about.